# Is @Stateless pointless for @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

Given this scenario :

```
-----
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class Start implements X {

@Inject
EjbOne ejbOne

public Integer getId(){...}
  return ejbOne.getId
}
-------

@Singleton
public class EjbOne{

@Inject
EjbTwo ejbtwo;

public  Integer getId(){
    ../code omitted as not relevant

    ejbtwo.persist(..)

    ../code omitted as not relevant
  }
}
-------
@Singleton
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class EjbTwo {

public void persist(..){..}

}
------
```

Is it pointless having the @Singleton and TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW over EjbTwo as EjbTwo.persist(..) is already part of a 'forced' Transaction and called from a Singleton. I'm concerned with concurrency issues while persisting and also the possible bottleneck of having not just one but two singletons here.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by making EjbOne and EjbTwo singletons? This is not normally necessary

Comment: Hey Steve, I need to implement my own 'Identity Creator', so while persisting (my own uniquely creating Ids) I only want one instance to persist. My gut feeling is that marking EjbOne as @Singleton is pointless and unnecessary.  What are your thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Making EjbOne is likely pointless - yes. But you're far better off getting your database to create ids, or create UUIDs. Or get your JPA provider to manage it - it's less likely to mess it up than you.

Comment: Cheers @SteveC,  unfortunately the the actual ID creation is out of my control, however complete randomness will not do in this particular situation thats required. We need the exact same ID's created based on a number of inputs in the case of an outage. Cheers for the reply